# Certain Fonts not Visible

Tags: html, fonts, file-transfer

Hey I have my site set up on a server but I can't get certain fonts to show up. It will just all be 'times new roman' even though I transferred the .ttf files. Is there any way to fix this. The two fonts are 'abeatbyKai' and 'OptimusPrincepsSemiBold'

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are usually on your client, not the server.  You are trying to do [embedded fonts.](http://forum.fontlab.com/microsoft-web-embedding-fonts-tool-weft-b25.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can also send them to the client using the [@font-face](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/) declarations on your css files.